# Yii render view file of french showing special character

Tags: yii

when I am trying render view file of french it showing special character in the content instead of showing french alphabets even though my html lang="fr".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Need to put 'charset'=>'iso-8859-1', in config

and update meta for layout of file with

charset ?>'" />